# Android: setText("Loading...") inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, loading

I need to know how to make in AsyncTask a TextView with:

- Start: setText ("Loading.");
- 1 sec: setText ("Loading..");
- 2 sec: setText ("Loading...");
- Restart: setText ("Loading.");

During the real time of the actions of doInBackground. Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

    tareaAsincInicio = new tareaAsincronaInicio();
    tareaAsincInicio.execute();
}

private class tareaAsincronaInicio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        ...
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ...
        methods();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);  

        finish();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you need to update your textview every 1 second it would be better to use CountDownTimer:

Additional info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Here is example: http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html

You start this CountDownTimer in `onPreExecute()` and stop it in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a handler that you start `onPreExecute()`

```
string text = "Loading." 
boolean async = true;   
handler=new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if(text.contains("..."))
                 text = "Loading." else 
                        text = text+".";
            tv.setText(text);
            if(async)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

What this does is call a runnable every second that changes the text. When you reach `onPostExecute()`, you change the `async` value to false and the runnable is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `doInBackground` call `publishProgress()` and pass it the text you want to be displayed. Then in `onProgressUpdate()` set your text view.

```html
new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                publishProgress("updated text");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                textView.setText(values[0]);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a handler as a attribute then initiate  on pre execute and change dialog title in runnable interface